# python threading local unexpected value

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

Why is getattr not working? I am not trying to set a default value to threadLocal, I want to know why getattr does not work the way I want it to? tried to lock, same output

Expected Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
main thread
```

Current Output

```
0
0
0
0
0
main thread
```

Code

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import local

threadLocal = local()
threadLocal.x = 'main thread'

def f(x):
    # threadLocal.x = x # this works
    threadLocal.x = getattr(threadLocal, 'x', x) # this does not work
    return threadLocal.x

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
result = pool.map(f, range(0, 5))
for i in result:
    print(i)

print(threadLocal.x)
```

Comment: A thread local is attached to the thread. Changes in other threads do not chance the version in the main thread. And the new threads don't even see `x` from the main thread.

Comment: @KlausD maybe I did not explain it clearly, but `threadLocal.x = x` does what I want, why does not getting the value using getattr work?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough as well: because it does not exist in that thread.

Comment: the `x` in `getattr(threadLocal, 'x', x)` will not be a function local the one in the function argument? @KlausD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Thread *pool* shares its worker threads between work items. That means that if a work item is finished before the next, both can run on the same thread and thus see the same thread locals.

This is exactly what happens here: since `f` is very quick to execute, most or all work items run in the first worker thread. The first task `f(0)` sets `threadLocal.x = 0` here, and other tasks *running in the same thread* thus read `threadLocal.x = 0`.

You can circumvent this by (artificially) increasing the runtime of `f`.

```py
def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.2)  # delay for other work items to start running
    threadLocal.x = getattr(threadLocal, 'x', x) # this works now
    return threadLocal.x
```

Note that *any* additional operation may be sufficient to break the timing issue: that includes `print`ing the argument and thread local, for example.